# How to grab the value from an input and store the input value as the text of a new list item?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

When the user clicks the button with the ID of `generate-todo`, I want to grab the value from the input with the ID of `new-todo`, and  store the input value as the text of a new list item and append that new item to the unordered list with the class of `todos`. This is what I've tried so far but I'm missing something.

```js
  let todo = document.querySelector('#generate-todo').addEventListener('click', function() { 
        todo = document.querySelector('#new-todo').value;
      const create = document.createElement('li');
      document.querySelector('.todos').append(create);  
  });
```

```html
<label for="new-todo">Add a new item to the list:</label>
<input id="new-todo" type="text">
<button id="generate-todo">Add to the List!</button>
<h1>List of things to do</h1>
<ul class="todos">
</ul>
```

Comment: `document.querySelector('todos')` is missing the class identifier (period) :: `document.querySelector('.todos')`

Comment: You also never use the value. And `let todo =` can be removed; `addEventListener` doesn’t return anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should get you started

```js
document.getElementById('generate-todo').addEventListener('click', function() { 
        let todo = document.getElementById('new-todo').value;
      const li = document.createElement('li');
      li.innerText = todo;
      document.getElementById('todos').append(li);  
  });
```

```html
<label for="new-todo">Add a new item to the list:</label>
<input id="new-todo" type="text">
<button id="generate-todo">Add to the List!</button>
<h1>List of things to do</h1>
<ul id="todos">
</ul>
```

Comment: After the `.append(li)` I would add `document.getElementById('new-todo').value='';` (so I'd probably also assign element 'new-todo' to a variable for re-use)

Comment: Why does it give an error? returns: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'append')`

Comment: @KevinA Because there is no element with the ID `todos`.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `.` in `todos` selector.

```
document.querySelector(".todos").append(create)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function addToDo() {
  const text = document.getElementById("new-todo").value;
  const newItem = document.createElement('li');
  newItem.innerText = text;
  document.querySelector('.todos').appendChild(newItem);
  
  document.getElementById("new-todo").value = null;
}

document.getElementById("generate-todo").addEventListener('click', addToDo)
```